# Lightest Open Source PHP LMS

Tags: open-source, php, educational

I need a Learning Management System, Course Manager, Virtual Learning Environment or similar. I need it:

1. PHP, to design a web page.
2. Open Source.
3. As simple as possible: only with the basic features.
4. Lightweigh, basic, micro...

I have already tried thousands of web apps: Moodle, eFront, Chamilo, Claroline, Atutor and many others, even rare ones.

Do you know any appropriate for me?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I'm afraid your criteria are a bit broad: "simplest" and "lightest" are hard to measure, and not everyone knows what "moodle" is. It would be extremely helpful if you'd point out what features you need. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) – and then **[edit]** your post to fill the gaps. This also increases your chances to good, fitting answers. Thanks!